# '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'Version' error

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I run the following code:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_rest, y_train, y_rest = train_test_split(x, y, stratify=None,test_size=0.4)
```

I get this error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ade5fc6cc231> in <module>
      3 #from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
      4 
----> 5 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y, random_state=123, shuffle=True)
      6 
      7 # X_train, X_rest, y_train, y_rest = train_test_split(x, y, stratify=None,test_size=0.4)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2152         train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
   2153 
-> 2154     return list(chain.from_iterable((_safe_indexing(a, train),
   2155                                      _safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
   2156 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   2152         train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
   2153 
-> 2154     return list(chain.from_iterable((_safe_indexing(a, train),
   2155                                      _safe_indexing(a, test)) for a in arrays))
   2156 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _safe_indexing(X, indices, axis)
    393         return _pandas_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype, axis=axis)
    394     elif hasattr(X, "shape"):
--> 395         return _array_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype, axis=axis)
    396     else:
    397         return _list_indexing(X, indices, indices_dtype)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _array_indexing(array, key, key_dtype, axis)
    172 def _array_indexing(array, key, key_dtype, axis):
    173     """Index an array or scipy.sparse consistently across NumPy version."""
--> 174     if np_version < parse_version('1.12') or issparse(array):
    175         # FIXME: Remove the check for NumPy when using >= 1.12
    176         # check if we have an boolean array-likes to make the proper indexing

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'Version'
```

Comment: This is an sklearn bug, could you file an issue on their github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those facing this issue, go to ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils_*init*_.py
In line 174, remove np_version < parse_version('1.12'), save and restart Jupyter.
This works for me

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's really looks like a bug in `sklearn`. Seems like `Version` was a namedtuple before (therefore, was comparable with ordinary touples). ¯\_(ツ)_/¯